# Hibernate: HashSet object in POJO changes to PersistentSet after session.saveOrUpdate()

Tags: hibernate

I have a simple Hibernate 1 to M code. When I save the Employee object, the child object inside Employee POJO which is java.util.HashSet before save becomes org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet after session.saveOrUpdate().

```
private static void addEmployee() {
    System.out.println("Entering addEmployee **********");
    Session session = HibernateSessionUtil.getSession("test/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    Employee1toM employee1toM = new Employee1toM();
    employee1toM.setEmployeeFirstName("Jitendra");
    employee1toM.setEmployeeLastName("Patil");

    EmployeeAddress1toM employeeAddress1toM = new EmployeeAddress1toM();
    employeeAddress1toM.setEmployeeArea("ABC");
    employeeAddress1toM.setEmployeeCity("DEF");
    employeeAddress1toM.setEmployeeState("IJK");

    employeeAddress1toM.setEmployee1toM(employee1toM);
    employee1toM.getEmployeeAddress1toM().add(employeeAddress1toM);

    System.out.println(employee1toM.getEmployeeAddress1toM().getClass().getName());
    // prints java.util.HashSet

    Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(employee1toM);
    txn.commit();

    System.out.println(employee1toM.getEmployeeAddress1toM().getClass().getName());
    // prints org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet

    System.out.println("Leaving addEmployee **********");

}

OutPut:
Entering addEmployee **********
java.util.HashSet
Hibernate: insert into Employee1toM (EMPLOYEE_FIRSTNAME, EMPLOYEE_LASTNAME) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EmployeeAddress1toM (EMPLOYEE_AREA, EMPLOYEE_CITY, EMPLOYEE_STATE, EMPLOYEE_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet
Leaving addEmployee **********
```

The configuration and the POJOs are straightforward so I am not sharing it. Please help me understanding how can I stop auto-conversion of **HashSet** to **PersistentSet** type.